# Running an TADOStoredProc and forget

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, delphi

There's some way to call TADOStoredProc.Execute returning immediately
and forgetting about it?
Something in the lines:

```
// Creating the TDOStoredProc

try
  Sproc.Execute; // Returning immediately
  // Connection remains open
finnaly
  Sproc.Free;
end;
```

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support *way* back in July **2019**, over *4 years ago*. It is long past time you implemented your finalised upgrade plan. Running such an old version is a security concern for you and your customers.

Comment: Running in another thread?

Comment: @ThomA have you ever heard of bureaucracy? That decision is not in my hands, I work with the tools we have. The system runs smoothly on MSSQL 2019, by the way. But the move didn't happen yet.

Comment: You would also be surprised how many people are blindly using such an outdated, and unsecure version, @FabricioAraujo . If your employer really is refusing to upgrade, I would reminding them *every day* of the problem. Depending on the industry (and part of the world) you work in, it can actually also be considered a breach by your governing body. Considering the world we live in, I feel reminding people of the security flaw they have is a *must*.

Comment: Not easily for forget. Yes, for continuing without waiting by having ExecuteOptions include eoAsyncExecute. To forget you would have to kick off a task that then executes the stored procedure.

Comment: @Brian If by friday (2023/11/3) no one comes with another way, please convert that comment in a answer and I will close the question accepting your answer.

Comment: @Brian Please convert your comment in a answer.